# I don't understand the "...been one to..." expression in this sentence

Tags: meaning-in-context, expressions

I went to see the definition of the word "grudge" and came across this example from Google:

> I've never **been one to** hold a grudge.

I rarely seen this "been one to" expression and would be much appreciated if someone could give me more examples of it in different contexts so I can comprehend how to use it.

Comment: **Not be one to do something:** *to not be the type of person who would do a particular thing* - From Macmillan dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Not be one to do something:** to not be the type of person who would do a particular thing. - [Macmillan dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/amp/dictionary/british/not-be-one-to-do-something)

If you say that someone is *not one to do something*, you think that it is very unlikely that they would do it because it is not their normal behaviour. - [Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/amp/english/not-one-to-do-something)

This is an expression for talking about things that you don't usually do.

The sentence you've given means that *you have never been the kind of person who holds grudges*.